# WSO2 authentication certificates

Tags: authentication, wso2, authorization, wso2-cep, wso2-esb

Is it possible to use authentication certificates to connect to WSO2 (CEP) Admin Services?

```
https://localhost:9443/services/UserAdmin?wsdl
```

If yes, so how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing Admin Services APIs are common for all the WSO2 products. You have to use the public certificate used by the product inorder to communicate on SSL.

You may refer the following sample

```
import org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.LoginAuthenticationExceptionException;  
import org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.LogoutAuthenticationExceptionException;  
import org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.stub.types.carbon.ServiceMetaData;  
import org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.stub.types.carbon.ServiceMetaDataWrapper;  

import java.rmi.RemoteException;  

public class ListServices {  
  public static void main(String[] args)  
      throws RemoteException, LoginAuthenticationExceptionException,  
          LogoutAuthenticationExceptionException {  
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "$CEP_HOME/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks");  
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");  
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");  
    String backEndUrl = "https://localhost:9443";  

    LoginAdminServiceClient login = new LoginAdminServiceClient(backEndUrl);  
    String session = login.authenticate("admin", "admin");  
    ServiceAdminClient serviceAdminClient = new ServiceAdminClient(backEndUrl, session);  
    ServiceMetaDataWrapper serviceList = serviceAdminClient.listServices();  
    System.out.println("Service Names:");  
    for (ServiceMetaData serviceData : serviceList.getServices()) {  
      System.out.println(serviceData.getName());  
    }  

    login.logOut();  
  }  
}
```

For more information, check [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/WSO2+Admin+Services)